# Distributed transactions with RabbitMQ in spring boot application

Tags: java, transactions, microservices, distributed-transactions

Currently working on migrating a monolith app into micro services and I want to know how to achieve the distributed transaction in across application. Is there any examples for RabbitMQ handling distributed transaction?

please note that this is not a duplicate question. also i come with some example but i didn't find any implementation.

http://lifeinide.com/post/2017-12-29-spring-boot-rabbitmq-transactions/

Answer (score 3):

Generally in microservices world, distributed transaction using 2PC protocol is discouraged as it slow and not scalable. Rather a pattern known as [Saga](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) is recommended. Failures are rolled-back using  compensation steps or activities in reverse order. The whole idea is to let microservices do only local transactions and the transaction which span across microservices should be done in a scalable manner and using a strategy where failed transactions can be logically compensated locally. Saga pattern can use a messaging broker where events can be pushed to and listened to - this is where you can use RabbitMQ.
An example project can be seen [here](https://github.com/hamzoni/rabbitmq-saga-demo) and [here](https://github.com/eventuate-tram/eventuate-tram-examples-customers-and-orders).

Comment: Hi thanks for your message. can you please some more clarity about sagas type like Choreography, Orchestration. also how can use message broker there?.

Comment: As mentioned in the shared link  "A saga is a sequence of local transactions. Each local transaction updates the database and publishes a message or event to trigger the next local transaction in the saga. If a local transaction fails because it violates a business rule then the saga executes a series of compensating transactions that undo the changes that were made by the preceding local transactions." So you keep on making local transactions in each microservice and send the message to next microservice on a broker. The other broker listens to the message and updates itself in transaction.

Comment: So rather than calling each service and performing distributed transaction - the service A performs its own transaction and drops a message to service B on broker. Service B reads the message performs local transaction on own datastore. If B fails it drops a compensation message to broker where service A is also listening which will compensate ( logical rollback the transaction it did).

Comment: In case of Orchestrator, there is a component which signals to  microservice A to commit locally and if successful signals to microservice B to commit locally. If B fails then Orchestrator signals service A to compensate. This signalling is typically an API call.

Comment: I have used Choreography in production with ActiveMQ as a broker for an ecommerce company quite successfully where multiple microservices subsribe to the queue/topic of their interest and update their local databases on relevant events raised from other microservices. It's a good way to scale the system.

Comment: ok thanks. so you are saying that Choreography has more advantages than Orchestrator right?. also is there any sample piece of code for Choreography with gradle?

Comment: also, how can i roll back both the cases.

Comment: rollback is actually compensation. This is done via sending an compensation event to the broker where the service on which the compensation needs to happens is listening.

Comment: ok but can you give some example code for saga with rollback?.previous github link is not working properly.